# How to inject arguments into scanf?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I have a C program that starts with `int main()` and somewhere in the code has a `scanf(%d %c %d, &num1, &ch, &num2)`.

Now I have another bash script that needs to test the C program. I want the bash script to run the C program and inject the arguments it received as input into the scanf (without making the C program stop and wait for input).

How can I do that?

Comment: You are not using & and " " in scanf in the given example.

Comment: @Sanjay-sopho edited, thanks

Comment: `foo < bar`, `cat bar | foo`?

Comment: `echo "$@" | foo`

Comment: @EOF, I think you mean, `foo < bar`

Comment: @selbie: I noticed, thank you.

Comment: What is that? If anything - `OUT=$(.\cprogram "1a1")` and then do something with that

Comment: Generally speaking, unless you can be 100% *sure* the input is in the expected format, you're better off `fgets()`'ing the whole line and `str...()` parsing it in memory. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a text file with the input you want, space delimited.

For example, for the `scanf("%d %c %d", &num1, &ch, &num2);` statement the contents of `testinput.txt` would be:

```
42 x 99
```

Save this file to the same directory as your program.

Now run your program using input redirection

```
 ./yourprogram < testinput.txt
```

scanf will read from `testinput.txt` instead of from the console.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a file? Just with text?

Comment: @UFCInsider Yes, pipe `echo` into your program.

Comment: `echo "2 a 9" | ./myprogram` is what you want.